# Attaching a Drag Handler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag

I'm trying to create a OnDrag event handler I can't seem to get it to work.  I've been watching the youtube tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSnZuBhOA2U and followed his instructions step for step.  But for some reason when I debug, I notice that `Start()` method runs, but the `OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)` or `OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)` or `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)` are never triggered.

Here is my full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    private Image bgImage;
    private Image joystickImage;
    private Vector3 inputVector;

    private void Start()
    {
        bgImage = GetComponent<Image>();
        joystickImage = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
        Debug.Log("Test Started");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 pos;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImage.rectTransform, eventData.position,
            eventData.pressEventCamera, out pos))
        {
            Debug.Log("Test Works");
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it was not firing is that I was missing EventSystem in my Hirearchy.  The youtube video failed to mention that.  Problem is solved.